# How to get Visual Studio 2017 to highlight matching XML tags, and have indent lines for XML?

Tags: xml, visual-studio

I'm pretty sure this functionality doesn't exist in VS 2017 (not sure about 2019 but I somehow doubt it does), but wanted to check if anyone knows if it's possible to enable element tag highlighting (if clicked into an element tag, highlight the closing tag) and indent guidelines for XML.

If it's not an OOB, are there any extensions to do those things for XML? I haven't been able to find any, but my google-fu seems to be weak today.

Thanks!

Comment: the moment when notepad++ is a more powerful editor